# View image file written to filesystem using FileWriter in gallery in IOS using phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am writing a image file to the IOS Filesystem using phonegap File API (FileWriter). I am able to write the file successfully however it does not show up in the gallery. Is there a specific location on the fileSystem i should be writing this file in order for it to be visible in the gallery ? . Or is there any other way to achieve this (i will have to write the file using file writer as i am getting a response from a service in binary/base64 )

Answer (score 1):

`FileWriter` writes to the phone memory inside the app sandbox.

If you want to save it in the gallery you can use [this plugin](https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin)